# I have issues with rspec syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to write unit tests for a model using rspec. I want to write tests for associations as well. I don't know how to start. Can anyone help me sort this out?

**job model**

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company

  has_attached_file :image, styles: {medium: "800x800>", thumb: "100x100>"}, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :title, length: {minimum: 5, maximum: 15}
  validates :description,length: {minimum: 10, maximum: 400}
```

**job_spec.rb**

```
RSpec.describe Job, type: :model do
  it "ensures title presence" do
    # job=Job.new(title:'software engineer').save
    expect(job).to validate_presence_of(:title)
  end
end
```

Comment: This question doesn't show much effort in trying to solve the problem by yourself at the beginning. Start googling for solutions, rspec is well-documented testing framework. One good place to get help is relishapp: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/model-specs or betterspecs: http://www.betterspecs.org/ Stackoverflow is not a place where to let other people do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The gem [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) solves this problem with ActiveRecord matchers.

```
RSpec.describe Job, type: :model do
  it { should belong_to(:user) }
end
```

To test associations, you can use the following matchers:

- `belong_to`: tests your belongs_to associations.
- `have_and_belong_to_many`: tests your has_and_belongs_to_many
  associations.
- `have_many`: tests your has_many associations.
- `have_one`: tests your has_one associations.

You can even test validations using ActiveModel matchers.

Learn more in the [**documentation page**](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers).